# How to fix unicode special character mis-encoding?

Tags: r, linux, character-encoding

I have some sort of a problem with the encoding or system locale. On our server (AlmaLinux 9.2) I get,

```
> x <- '10±1'
> x
[1] "10\302\2611"
```

whereas on my machine (Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS) it is fine:

```
> x <- '10±1'
> x
[1] "10±1"
```

This also applies to e.g. `'`, `<`, `>`.

Both systems **R version 4.3.1** running.

I noticed that on the server with `localectl` only `LANG=de_CH.UTF-8` is set, whereas on my machine all the `LANG, LC_NUMERIC, LC_TIME, ...` variables are set. My intuition is to set on the server `LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8` to set all the presumably missing variables at once.

However, **1.** what strikes me is that `UTF-8` should be already set with the `LANG` variable, also I set `LANG = "C"; LC_ALL = "C"` in my `.Renviron`, and **2.** I have to use my `.bashrc` to make settings, already tried `LC_ALL = "C"` there and `source .basrc` it, but with no changes.

A co-occuring problem is that `r --vanilla` shows these guys during startup:

```
During startup - Warning messages:
1: Setting LC_CTYPE failed, using "C" 
2: Setting LC_COLLATE failed, using "C" 
3: ...
```

Not sure where exactly to look at, thanks for any hints.

Comment: Thanks @MrFlick, I included that information!

Comment: How did you install R on these machines? Did you build from source? Or use some distribution manager? I'm wondering if they might have different compile flags or something. If you `cat()` the value of `x` rather than print it on the AlmaLinux does it render as you expect?

Comment: @MrFlick Not sure, I didn't set up the server, but I can't see it in `yum list installed`. Interesting, `cat(x)` indeed yields `10±1` correctly!

Comment: @MrFlick No, wait, I see `R.x86_64, R-core.x86_64, R-core-devel.x86_64, R-devel.x86_64` in the list.